# Type error in Monad definition

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to learn about Monads in Haskell. 
Given the data type:

```
data XY a = X a | Y a
```

I would like `'X a >>= f'` to return `'f a'` and `'Y a >>= f'` to just ignore `'f'` and return `'Y a'`.

This is the code I wrote:

```
  4 instance Monad XY where
  5         return x = X x
  6         (X a) >>= f = f a
  7         (Y a) >>= f = Y a
```

and this is the compiler error I got:

```
prog.hs:7:25:
    Couldn't match expected type `b' with actual type `a'
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for >>= :: XY a -> (a -> XY b) -> XY b
          at prog.hs:6:9
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for >>= :: XY a -> (a -> XY b) -> XY b
          at prog.hs:6:9
    In the first argument of `Y', namely `a'
    In the expression: Y a
    In an equation for `>>=': (Y a) >>= f = Y a
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Could you help me understandiq what I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the type of `>>=`:

```
(>>=) :: XY a -> (a -> XY b) -> XY b
```

With your case for `Y a >>= f`, you're returning an `XY a`, not an `XY b`. That's why the type error is telling you it can't match an expected `b` with the actual `a`.

In general what you're trying to do (always return `Y a`) doesn't make sense because `XY` only has one type parameter that you can't change without also changing the value `Y a`. Have a look at the [`Monad` instance for `Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Instances.html) to see how this kind of thing can be done with a slightly different type.