# standard specialization of Either where type of Left and Right is the same

Tags: scala, haskell, types

Is there a standard specialization of `Either` in Haskell or Scala that makes the types contained in the `Left` and `Right` the same type?

In Haskell, I want something like this:

```
data SpecializedEither a = Left a | Right a
```

This might also be considered a slight generalization of `Maybe` that makes `Nothing` hold a value.

*edit*: Ganesh raises a very good point that a Monad instance can't be defined for this type.  Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: `(Bool, a)` is close if you squint

Comment: I considered it, but then I would have to go out of my way to write the Monad instance for it. I was hoping there was something [standand] I could just use.

Comment: This recent question shows why you can't actually get a Monad instance for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24233245/type-error-in-monad-definition

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam That only shows that the "standard instance" for `Either` fails, right? There are other instances that would work for `SpecializedEither`.

Comment: Oh, true, though I'm not sure if any of the alternatives would make much sense.

Comment: @illabout - what are you trying to do? :-) The problem with generalizing `Maybe` to have `Nothing` hold a value of the same type as `Just` shows up precisely when you try to define the `Monad` instance.

Comment: Scala has a `MergeableEither[A]` that `Either[A, A]` can be implicitly converted to, but it exists mostly to provide a `merge`—it doesn't expose any other methods.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam `Either a a` is isomorphic to `(a,Bool)`. If `(a,Bool)` is a monad, then because of polymorphism (i.e. free theorems), `return a = (a,someBool)`, and `(a,b) >>= f` mathematically _must_ apply `f` to `a` and then combine the two Bools somehow, i.e. give the same result as the definition `(a,b) >>= f = let (c,b') = f a in (c,b # b')` for some function `(#)`. The monad laws for `return` work exactly when `someBool` is an identity for `#`, and the associative monad law works exactly when `#` is associative. We use any Monoid structure on Left & Right to make `Monad (Either a a)`

Comment: Oh - just realised I've reinvented [J.Abrahamson's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24238139/1598537). Oops.

Comment: Right, that was also the point kosmikus made. What I was actually trying to say is that instance I think the O.P. wants (where 'errors' are propagated) is impossible.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam, You're correct. I had wanted something like `Maybe` where the errors propagate, but it looks like it is impossible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's [a standard `Monad` instance on `((,) e)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html) so long as `e` is a `Monoid`

```
instance Monoid e => Monad ((,) e) where
  return a = (mempty, a)
  (e1, a) >>= f = let (e2, b) = f a in (e1 <> e2, b)
```

Since `Either a a` and `(Bool, a)` are isomorphic (in two ways), we get a `Monad` instance as soon as we pick a `Monoid` for `Bool`. There are two (really four, see comments) such `Monoid`s, the "and" type and the "or" type. Essentially, this choice ends up deciding as to whether the `Left` or `Right` side of your either is "default". If `Right` is default (and thus `Left` overrides it) then we get

```
data Either1 a = Left1 a | Right1 a

get1 :: Either1 a -> a
get1 (Left1 a) = a
get1 (Right1 a) = a

instance Monad Either1 where
  return = Right1
  x >>= f = case (x, f (get1 x)) of
    (Right1 _, Right1 b) -> Right1 b
    (Right1 _, Left1  b) -> Left1  b
    (Left1  _, y       ) -> Left1 (get1 y)
```

Comment: Technically there are two more monoid possibilities for `Bool`s, given by the `(==)` and `(/=)` (aka "xor") operators, although those aren't predefined in `Data.Monoid`.

Comment: That's a good point. I had never checked to see that those satisfy the laws as well.

Comment: There are already newtype wrappers for the "or" and "and" monoids on `Bool`, defined in `Data.Monoid`, named `Any` and `All`, and the `Monad ((,) e)` instance is equivalent to the `Writer` monad.  So I suspect `Writer Any` or `Writer All` are the desired monads here.

Comment: @AndrewC `True == b` = `False /= b` = `b`

Comment: @J.Abrahamson No - I made a mistake!

Comment: @LouisWasserman I may have understated how "standard" that instance is :)

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Thanks.  This was really helpful!  In your `get1` function, I think you meant to pattern match on `Left1` and `Right1`, not `Left` and `Right`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I'm not sure I really understand how the `Monad` instance for `((,) e)` is equivalent to `Writer Any` or `Writer All`.  Would you be able to write up an example showing how this works?  Or @J.Abrahamson could add it to his answer.

Comment: @illabout `Writer w a`is equivalent to `(w, a)` with exactly the same monad instance I gave here. Any and All are wrappers around Bool which give it two (of the four) kinds of Monoid semantics. So, `Writer Any` and `Writer All` are two versions of `((,) Bool)` with well-defined monad instances. Obviously, Writer is a popular construction so it goes far to say that this kind of monad is "standard".

Comment: And fixed! Glad this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
type Foo[T] = Either[T, T]
val x: Foo[String] = Right("")
// Foo[String] = Right()
```